# List comprehension for np matrixes

Tags: python, numpy

I have two np.matrixes, one of which I'm trying to normalize. I know, in general, list comprehensions are faster than for loops, so I'm trying to convert my double for loop into a list expression.

```
# normalize the rows and columns of A by B
 for i in range(1,q+1):
     for j in range(1,q+1):
         A[i-1,j-1] = A[i-1,j-1] / (B[i-1] / B[j-1])
```

This is what I have gotten so far:

```
A = np.asarray([A/(B[i-1]/B[j-1]) for i, j in zip(range(1,q+1), range(1,q+1))])
```

but I think I'm taking the wrong approach because I'm not seeing any significant time difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think list comprehensions are generally faster than loops? Given that you actually use a for loop in your comprehension.

Comment: You shouldn't use list comprehensions *or* `for` loops with NumPy arrays unless you really have no better option.

Comment: Thought  list comprehensions are usually a tiny bit faster than the for loop  because it doesn't have to look up the list and its append method on every iteration.

Comment: Usually not significantly so. The biggest issue with what you are trying to do is that you are using vanilla Python instead of vectorized `numpy` operations. Concentrate on *that*, not using a list-comprehension.

Comment: In your double loop you modify `A` inplace.  In the comprehension, you make a new array, from the list.  That cancels out any time savings the comprehension might have over the loop.  Think of a comprehension as a streamlined way of doing a list append loop.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you really do mean `np.matrix`, stop using `np.matrix`. It has all sorts of nasty incompatibilities, and its role is obsolete now that `@` for matrix multiplication exists. Even if you're stuck on a Python version without `@`, using the `dot` method with normal ndarrays is still better than dealing with `np.matrix`.

You shouldn't use any sort of Python-level iteration construct with NumPy arrays, whether `for` loops or list comprehensions, unless you're sure you have no better options. Assuming A is 2D and B is 1D with shapes `(q, q)` and `(q,)` respectively, what you should instead do for this case is

```
A *= B
A /= B[:, np.newaxis]
```

[broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the operation over `A`. This will allow NumPy to perform the iteration at C level directly over the arrays' underlying data buffers, without having to create wrapper objects and perform dynamic dispatch on every operation.